# gitbook TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: git, github, gitbook

I don't know why this is mistake. Who can help me?

```
warn: "options" property is deprecated, use config.get(key) instead 
warn: "page.progress" property is deprecated 
warn: "sections" property is deprecated, use page.content instead 
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem with rel. 2.6.7, try to update your `gitbook`:

```
$ gitbook update
```

In order to know your versions:

```
$ gitbook ls
GitBook Versions Installed:
   * 3.1.1
     2.6.7
```